# getName() function not retrieving name

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm working on a graph, and one of the first things I have to do is find objects by their name from the data file and their location in a continent in a world.

I created a function for the objects called "getName()"

```
string CCountry::getName()
{
return *name;
}
```

The following code loops. It recognizes that there are 9 CCountry's in tempCont, and it gets to the inner loop where it does not pull up any name for the country, (I checked, they do have names), and then goes into a seg fault.

```
for (list<CContinent>::iterator it=world.begin(); it != world.end(); it++)
    {
        list<CCountry> *tempCont = it->getCountries();
        for (list<CCountry>::iterator it2=tempCont->begin(); it2 != tempCont->end(); it2++)
        {   
            cout << it2->getName() << flush;
            if (it2->getName() == homeCountryName)
            {
                *homeCountry = *it2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: My first thought would be to check whether `name == NULL` in `getName()`. Also, it may be a better idea to return it by constant reference (`const string &`), or constant pointer to constant (`const string * const`).

Comment: What type is `name`? Is the `string` you are referring to in `getName` actually `std::string`? `name` seems like a pointer: who allocated it? Who is responsible to deallocate it? Why aren't you using a `std::string` in first place for it? Can you post the actual definition of the whole `CCountry` class?

Comment: All this use of pointers is suspect.